# Solving this inhomogeneous second order linear ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to solve a PDE and ended up trying to find a solution for this:

$$g_{xx} + w^2g = -f(x)$$
$$g(0)=g(\pi)=0$$

---

Here is my attempt:

$$r^2 + \omega^2 r = 0$$
$$g_h(x) = Ae^{-\omega ^2x}+B$$

However the particular solution is

$$g_p(x) = Cf(x)$$
$$Cf_{xx} + \omega^2 Cf = -f$$
$$C = \frac{-f}{f_{xx}+\omega^2 f}$$

$$g(x) = Ae^{-\omega ^2x}+B + \frac{-f^2}{f_{xx}+\omega^2 f}$$

Does this make sense?

Comment: Your homogeneous solution is incorrect, $g_{xx}=A\omega^4e^{-\omega^2x}$.

Comment: The characteristic equation is $r^2 + w^2 = 0$. Also, without knowing what $f(x)$ is, you can't know the particular solution.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, you cannot assume the particular solution is $C f(x) $ without knowing $f(x)$. You could formulate a general expression for it using the method of variation of parameters though

Answer (score 1):

The homogeneous solution should be oscillatory, not exponentially decaying. In addition, the particular solution will only work if it satisfies the differential equation; we have no guarantee that $Cf(x)$ does the job. If it does; great, but I doubt it will.

It looks to me that the best way to tackle this problem is with Fourier series. Try to decompose $f(x)$ into a sum of sines and cosines, then use the ansatz $g = \sum_n a_n \sin(nx)$. We choose an ansatz of this form because of the boundary conditions you specified. Then plug in this ansatz in the differential equation and solve for the coefficients.

Alternatively, you can Fourier transform both sides of the equation and see what you get.

Comment: he/she is right. get the general form of solutions, blow 1 coefficient away for BC at 0. then solve the eigenfunction problem. substitute back to get a fourier series form of solution

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to solve your second order linear nonhomogeneous ODE using [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second_order_equation). Make sure you distinguish the cases where $\omega$ is an integer, though.